# Multiple query Mysql with aliases

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two queries and has to be executed in one query execution. for eg

```
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c1 FROM table WHERE condition1";
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c2 FROM table WHERE condition2";

$result = mysqli->query($query1 ." UNION ".$query2);

while($res = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  print $res;
}
```

i have to get two counts as seperate c1 and c1;

By executing the above code i got {"c1":"number of counts"}

What may be the possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to add c1 and c2 and get one total count as result?

Comment: No get seperate results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
SUM(
CASE WHEN condition1 
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END) AS c1,

SUM(
CASE WHEN condition2 
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END) AS c2,

FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```
$result = mysqli->query($query1 ." UNION ALL".$query2);
```

Answer (score 1):

change the sql query

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE condition1) as c1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE condition2) as c2
FROM table
```

Comment: that also worked for me but i had to put DISTINCT for outer select to get me single result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have two queries and has to be executed in one query execution.

Nope, you don't.

Just run them in 2 separate calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this to get count:

```
$count = 0;
while($res = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $count += array_sum($res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i meant to get seperate count.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) count1, td2.count2
FROM table1 td1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT table2_id, count(*) count2 FROM  table2 WHERE condition2 )td2
ON td2.table2_id = td1.table1_id
WHERE condition1
```